# Q: sbt 1.1.5 distribution

Tags: scala, sbt

The [sbt 1.1.4 distribution](https://piccolo.link/sbt-1.1.4.zip) contains 1 subfolder (`2.12.4\`) in installed directory

```
C:\sbt-1.1.4\lib\local-preloaded\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\
```

The [sbt 1.1.5 distribution](https://piccolo.link/sbt-1.1.5.zip) contains 2 subfolder (`2.12.4\` and `2.12.6\`) in installed directory

```
C:\sbt-1.1.5\lib\local-preloaded\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\
```

Is that needed for sbt to run properly ?!

Comment: I think you have that folder because you had 1.1.4 installed before. How did you install each version?

Comment: Have a look at the contents of the zip archive for version 1.1.5  on the sbt download page !